# How to fix slow Magento website when pinging it?

Tags: performance, magento, ping

i have a huge problem:

When start ping to website via Prompt Command it time out.

See image here please - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVH6S.png

Tell me: It is hosting or Magento configuration issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: Your host should be configured to allow ping

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hosting issue, please ask your hosting company to get your server to respond to ICMP (ping) requests.